# how to get length of JSON Objects in Array which was written from server?

Tags: arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have JSON array that written in Objects in Array.
how to get the length of Key's inside object and values.
can any help me out to get the length of an object inside an array
I'm able to get array length but not able to get object key's and values lengths in a separate way

```
<code>
var data = [
{
  "SKUId": "1060",
  "LineID": "J97TSY8DA6",
  "State": "W",
  "Site": "0002",
  "Facility": "LCLHAVEN",
  "BizId": "BIZ1",
  "OwnerId": "LOOTC",
  "Status": "00",
  "Unit": "EA",
  "Qty": 28915.0,
  "QtyAllocated": 0.0,
  "QtyAssigned": 0.0,
  "QtyOrderIn": 0.0,
  "QtyDueIn": 0.0,
  "QtyOrderOut": 0.0,
  "QtyDueOut": 0.0,
  "StockLevelIndicator": "00",
  "DateLastMoved": "2018-06-14T20:40:27",
  "Product": null
 }
];
</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this.

```
Object.size = function(obj) { // it takes object as parameter and it returns the size of the object.
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(data[0]);
```